# How to fix screen disturtion while mouse over actions?

Tags: display, mouse, graphics

i installed elementary OS 5.1 on a acer aspire I3 machine with an ATI Readon mobility HD 5450 graphic chip. Now i have screen disturtions while mouse over like show in the append picture. Any ideas? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but that workaround did not work on my machine.